# How to Randomly positions a player within a dungeon map

Tags: java

I'm working at a dungeon game and facing a question which is how to randomly positions a player within a dungeon map.

two main requirement of the game is

1. Create a class Map that:
   Reads one of the sample ASCII-art map files (your code should be able to load any map written    in the same format).
   Stores the map information in a 2D array (int[][] or char[][]).
2. Create a class GameLogic that:
   Uses Map to load a map from file.
   Randomly positions a player within a map (on a non-wall space).
   the map looks like [Import ascii world map in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21754540/import-ascii-world-map-in-java) this webside shown. 
   Thank you

Comment: Have a function that generates random row and column number and test it against the map to ensure it is non-wall space. Repeat until one is found. If you need to create multiple players, then also make sure the positions of previous players are marked as invalid so they won't spawn in the same location.

Answer (score 1):

While you load the map, keep track of which cells are valid (maybe an array with the cell numbers?) and then, when you have to place the player, you take a random number between 0 and the length of the array - 1, check which cell number it refers to and that's the cell where the player goes.